# "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $j.." while testing in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am new to jasmine test cases. I was trying to write a test case for one of the scenarios where we are using `$j.map()` function ($j as in jquery) in our controller. When the test is executed the spec fails with the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $j in xyzController.js.
```

I changed it to JavaScript `array.map()` and the test case passed with no error.

The problem is I need to use jQuery map since `array.map` does not work in IE8 and jQuery map does. Though I can use shim/polyfill provided by MDN, but I'm hoping we can make it work without adding anything extra.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: How are you bundling/etc. and running your tests? Is there actually a jQuery present?

Comment: im using gulp for bundling my files

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after a lot of troubleshooting and going through forums and searching net, i found a solution. I had to install **karma-jasmine-jquery-2** (not karma-jasmine-jquery, as that gave error that it could not connect to github, when installing via NPM), as discussed on this forum: https://github.com/bessdsv/karma-jasmine-jquery/issues/8#issuecomment-215121620

Then followed karma-jasmine-jquery's usage from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-jquery#usage

and that solved my $j dependency issue.